# Collect a list of placeholders from an old style Python format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have an old-style format string (used in logging), like

```
'%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(category)s %(message)s'
```

However, I don’t know in advance what placeholders can be present except the standard ones allowed by the `logging` module.

Other than a regex, is there a way to extract the placeholder names from such strings?

Comment: You could start by splitting on '%', but a regex will be much easier. Why not use one?

Comment: What is the final use of the format string? `str.format`?

Comment: No, % formatting (`fmt % {'key': value}`)